# How to send an additional information in the response of a REST API

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-web-api, http-headers, multipartform-data

I have a GET API which returns an object of a particular class. I want to send additional information ( a number) without modifying the object in the response.

Following options came to my mind : 
1) Using some header value and updating it and send the response(but I think that using headers would be a bad practice in this scenario).
2)Send a multipart response.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If there is no way you can change the response and you need just simple data like numbers, it's OK to use HTTP headers in your response. You can see [sample](http://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/paging-in-aspnet-webapi-http-headers) how to do paging using HTTP headers.